# GraphQL Python Strawberry refactor common types

Tags: graphql, strawberry-graphql

I am using Python 3.10 and Strawberry 0.139

Is there any way to refractor out like-terms to write less code for defining types?

Lets say I have two types in my schema

```
@strawberry.type
class Home(Address):
    name: str 
    location: str 
    description: str
    phone: int

@strawberry.type
class Business(Address):
    name: str 
    fax: int
    location: str 
    description: str
    phone: int
```

Is there a way I can refractor out like terms in a class using the abc library. Note that I am not referring to [interfaces](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/) where you have to write in the inherited code. Something like this:

```
from abc import ABC

class Contact(ABC):
    location: str 
    description: str
    phone: int

@strawberry.type
class Home(Address):
    name: str 

@strawberry.type
class Business(Address):
    name: str 
    fax: int
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inherit from a base `strawberry.type`. Unlike interfaces, the base type won't be in the schema (unless explicitly included).

```py
@strawberry.type
class Contact:
    location: str 
    description: str
    phone: int

@strawberry.type
class Home(Contact):
    name: str 

@strawberry.type
class Business(Contact):
    name: str 
    fax: int
```